# How to make Colorbox iframe to move with the scroll up/down?

Tags: jquery, css, popup, position, colorbox

I have an Colorbox iframe that links to another page.

The problem is, if I scroll up/down the window the Colorbox remains at it's initial position and I can't see it anymore.

Is there a way to make it follow the scroll up/down? My guess is that it can be solved with CSS positioning or something but I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks. Please let me know if this doesn't make sense I could provide with some screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what a "Colourbox" is but the usual way to do what you describe is:

```
#yourElement {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 50%;
}
```

This would keep your element 0px from the left and half way down the screen when you scroll.

Comment: ColorBox by Jack Moore (http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) is a popular jquery based "lightbox" plugin. It's incredible good work by Jack and folks use it for galleries and much more, including basic window management.)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably accomplish this by forking the plugin and writing some JS to do the trick.

ColorBox uses "div#colorbox" which is absolutely positioned and I believe the plugin calculates the CSS top and left attributes on the fly.

You'd have to look into revising those values on the fly as part of an event reacting to the window scroll.  Sounds like a useful enhancement.

You can fork the plugin from the authors site [jacklmoore.com/colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

All the best.